# Faster ResolveAssemblyReference Task

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to build my solution faster. 
From VS output window I see that the [ResolveAssemblyReference Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9ad3f294.aspx) takes much time.

How can I make it faster? Maybe I should specify paths for a Assembly Reference Resolve task.

All assemblies in my solution are in one folder. So this should be a fast operation.

I think it will be usefull for many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you read in the online documentation, the `ResolveAssemblyReference` task is used to determine the list of dependencies. From the online documentation:

> *Determines all assemblies that depend on the specified assemblies.
>   This includes second and **nth-order** dependencies.*

To improve your current build performance, here are two things you can do:

1. Reduce Dependencies
2. Set Copy Local to "False" for GAC Assembly References

### Reduce Dependencies

Since the task can search dependencies to the "nth-order", dependency reduction is your best option. The more dependencies a solution/project has, the slower the task will run.

### Set Copy Local to "False" for GAC Assembly References

Another thing you can do is make sure the [Copy Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) value is set to `false` for any assembly reference you **KNOW** will be in the GAC. This does not shave that much time off the evaluation process, but it will make sure Visual Studio is not spending time copying an assembly into the bin that is already accessible via the GAC. Keep in mind that if the target machine (where the app/library/etc. will be used) will not have a certain assembly in its GAC

Comment: Thank you for ansfer. "Copy Local" is false already for all assemblies. I know about this speed up before. Reducing Dependencies - is very hard... As i saw from target file, msdn internal classes, and msbuild log that assembly resolving process have very many unnecessary steps: many - many folders are checked for the last versions of assemblies. But i have only one directory that contains all assemblies (plus .NET assemblies like System.Core in GAC). There is no any need for this to spend so many time for resolving.

Comment: Understood. Having the assemblies in a location that is more quickly accessible (on build machine vs. on a network share, etc.) will provide a measure of improvement, but dependency reduction is still the key in this process. Dependency resolution is not just about resolving the physical locations of dependencies; the `ResolveAssemblyReference' task must essentially check all dependencies for all dependencies until it has determined an entire dependency chain/tree (hence the nth-order clause in the documentation). This is what can really slow things down.